# String of words - DP

Tags: algorithm

I have a string of words and I must determine the longest substring so that the latest 2 letters of a word must be the first 2 letters of a word after it.

For example, for the words:

st**ar**, **ar**tifa**ct**, book, **ct**enopho**re**, list, **re**ply

Edit: So the longest substring would be st**ar**, **ar**tifa**ct**, **ct**enopho**re**, **re**ply

I'm looking for an idea to solve this problem in **O(n)**. No code, I appreciate any sugestions on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

First, read in all words into a structure. (You don't really need to, but it's easier to work that way. You could also read them in as you go.)

Idea is to have a lookup table (such as a `Dictionary` in .NET), which will contain key value pairs such that each two last letters of a word will have an entry in this lookup table, and their corresponding value will always be the longest 'substring' found so far.

Time complexity is O(n) - you only go through the list once.

Logic:

```
maxWord <- ""
word <- read next word
initial <- get first two letters of word
end <- get last two letters of word

if lookup contains key initial //that is the longest string so far... add to it
    newWord <- lookup [initial] value + ", " + word
    if lookup doesn't contain key end //nothing ends with these two letters so far
        lookup add (end, newWord) pair
    else if lookup [end] value length < newWord length //if this will be the longest string ending in these two letters, we replace the previous one
        lookup [end] <- newWord
    if maxWord length < newWord length //put this code here so you don't have to run through the lookup table again and find it when you finish
        maxWord <- newWord
else //lookup doesn't contain initial, we use only the word, and similar to above, check if it's the longest that ends with these two letters
    if lookup doesn't contain key end
        lookup add (end, word) pair
    else if lookup [end] value length < word length
        lookup [end] <- word
    if maxWord length < word length
        maxWord <- word
```

The `maxWord` variable will contain the longest string.

Here is the actual working code in C#, if you want it: http://pastebin.com/7wzdW9Es

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to **O(n)** I have is this :

You should *mark* every word with an Id. Let's take your example :

st**ar** => 1st substring possible. Since you're looking for the longest substring, if a substring stars with **ar**, it's not the longest, because you can add star in the front.
let's set the star ID to **1**, and its string comparison is **ar**

**ar**tifa**ct** => the two first character matches the first possible substring. let's set the artifact ID to **1** as well, and change the string comparison to **ct**

**book** => the two first character don't match anything in the string comparisons (there's only **ct** there), so we set the book ID to **2**, and we add a new string comparison : **ok**

...

**list** => the first two character don't match anything in the string comparisons (**re** from ID == 1 and **ok** from ID ==2 ), so we create another ID = 3 and another string comparison

In the end, you just need to go through the IDs and see which one has the most elements. You can probably count it as you go as well.

The main idea of this algorithm is to memorize every substring we're looking for. If we find a match, we just update the right substring with the two new last characters, and if we don't, we add it to the "memory list"

Repeating this procedure makes it **O(n*m)**, with **m** the number of different IDs.

Comment: Does your method work for this (2 words added - in bold): "star, artifact, **argeta**, **tact**, book, ctenophore, list, reply"?

Comment: Oh, I haven't thought of this ... It probably won't. I can see how to adapt it, but it looks like it raises the complexity to n^2 :(